# 125% Zoom on webpage

Tags: javascript, html

How would I add a js function that zooms the webpage to 125% on loading?

I found a way to do it with buttons, but I want the webpage to auto-zoom on loading.

```
<button onclick="body.style.zoom='150%'">Zoom 150%</button>
```

I tried to put it into the body tag like the code below but it did not work...

```
<body onload="body.style.zoom='150%'">
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `document.body.style.zoom = "150%"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css solution:

```css
body{
    zoom: 125%;
}
```

inline javascript solution:

```html
<button
    onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.zoom='150%'"
>Click to zoom
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

simply ditch the js and use css

```
<body style="zoom:150%;">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body style="zoom:150%;">
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```